# Looping try-catch isn't working

Tags: java, try-catch, user-input, infinite-loop

How would I properly loop this try catch statement? From what I'm aware, the 
`playerIntInput = reader.nextInt();` within the try block is executed and it catches the exception if one exists, this should cause the `loop = false` to never be reached. Then it output the message in the catch block and it should loop back to the try and ask for input again. Instead I just get an infinitely looped output from the catch block.

```
void CheckInput(int playerIntInput) {
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop=true) {
        try {
            playerIntInput = reader.nextInt();
            loop = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid character was used, try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be loop == true, not loop = true

Comment: Just use `while(loop)`.

Comment: Using only `while(loop)` still results in an infinite loop for me. As does using `while(loop==true)`. I tried those prior too and the loop still happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the assignment operator `=`, so `loop` is always `true` when checked, instead of the `==` operator.  You could use `while(loop == true)`, but `loop` is already a `boolean`.  The simplest solution is `while(loop)`.

Also, if there's an error in `nextInt`, it won't consume the input.  Call `next()` in the `catch` block to consume the non-numeric input and advance past it.

Comment: Using only `while(loop)` still results in an infinite loop for me. As does using `while(loop==true)`. I tried those prior too and the loop still happened.

Comment: @userxbladeuserxblade Updated my answer; you must advance beyond the invalid input.

Comment: @ rgettman Forgive me for I'm still pretty amateur, but when using `next()` exactly what is it and do I need to put anything in the parentheses?

Comment: @userxbladeuserxblade Assuming that `reader` is a `Scanner`, calling `next()`, with no parameters, will consume the next token from the input, which is the non-numeric input on which `nextInt()` threw the exception.

Comment: @regettman So do I use it like this? `playerIntInput = reader.next();`

Comment: @userxbladeuserxblade No, just call `reader.next()`; it returns a `String`.  We don't care what it is any more, because it's not numeric, so don't even bother assigning it to any variable.

Comment: Another issue is arising now, when I finally do enter a number instead of a string, and it isn't thrown, the number defaults to 0 when I look at `playerIntInput` when it's output directly. Should I make a new question for this?